# SVGs in React - Webpack setup to out raw SVG and also use in Sass/CSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In a React project I need to use raw-loader to output an SVG sprite as HTML inside the opening body tag. This is needed for the project and can't be changed to be called via url or changed to use SVGs as React components.

That works fine, but the problem I face is on the odd occasion I also need to call SVGs in Sass for e.g as background-image:

```
background-image: url(path-to-svg);
```

This works well using an SVG loader like 'svg-url-loader' which outputs:

```
url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C?xml version='1.0'?%3E%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='52' height='52'...
```

But using just 'raw-loader' it outputs

```
url("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"52\" height=\"52\"...
```

Is there anyway to load SVGs as HTML in the DOM using raw-loader but also be able to load SVGs in Sass/CSS?

My current webpack setup is simply:

```
  {
      test: /\.(svg)$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader'
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if CSS loader can parse the way you want.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-load-svg-with-react-and-webpack I found this pretty helpful. However, it's slightly different from how you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that article was pretty useful but I couldn't manage to find a solution from their suggestions.

In the end however I did find a way. I changed my weback loader back to 'svg-url-loader' which fixed the svgs in sass/css but also broke my setup of injecting svg into HTML, but you can inline loaders in imports to only use that loader in specific situations.

So I used:

import {SVGFile} from '!raw-loader!path-to-svg.svg' and that fixed my issue :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!